# Using Fused Location Provider for Wikitude

Tags: javascript, fusedlocationproviderapi, wikitude

I previously used Android Location Manager to retrieve location. However, when I run wikitude apps, the POIs are loaded but are not displayed. I read a few posts saying that this may caused by basic Location Strategy. Therefore, I decided to use Fused Location Provider. The problem still occur. Please help me anyone

```js
package xyz.arlayer.scratch;


import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectStartupConfiguration;
import com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Augmented extends Activity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int WIKITUDE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 2;
    private ArchitectView architectView;

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;


    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_augmented);

        this.architectView = this.findViewById(R.id.architectView);
        final ArchitectStartupConfiguration config = new ArchitectStartupConfiguration();
        config.setLicenseKey("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");
        this.architectView.onCreate(config);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }


        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, WIKITUDE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }}

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        architectView.onPostCreate();
        try {
            architectView.load("file:///android_asset/08_Browsing$Pois_5_Native$Detail$Screen/index.html");        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        if (location!=null && Augmented.this.architectView != null ) {
            // check if location has altitude at certain accuracy level & call right architect method (the one with altitude information)
            if ( location.hasAltitude() && location.hasAccuracy() && location.getAccuracy()<7) {
                Augmented.this.architectView.setLocation( location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getAccuracy() );
            } else {
                Augmented.this.architectView.setLocation( location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.hasAccuracy() ? location.getAccuracy() : 1000 );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        architectView.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        architectView.onPause();

        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();

        architectView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: What location do you get in locationChanged in nativedetailscreen.js?

Comment: I run the code on another device. Turns out the code works well with another phone. I finally see the markers. Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Could it be that the phone where it is not working has no gyroscope? There is a issue in the Wikitude SDK 7.0 where POIs are not working if the device only has a compass, this will be fixed with the next release.

Comment: I guess that explains why. The phone that I used is pretty vintage >_<